# Magento 2.3.0 - Class MailCampaigns\Connector\Helper\MailCampaigns_API does not exist

Tags: api, magento2.3, helper, class

I installed the module (https://github.com/mailcampaigns/Magento2Connector) On my Magento (2.3.0 version) application.
It installed successfully but when I try to add a product to the cart.

It's throwing an error on the product page:

> **We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.**

**Error in exception log**

> main.CRITICAL: Class MailCampaigns\Connector\Helper\MailCampaigns_API does not exist {"exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: 0): Class MailCampaigns\Connector\Helper\MailCampaigns_API does not exist at /var/www/html/magento23/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:35, ReflectionException(code: 0): Class MailCampaigns\Connector\Helper\MailCampaigns_API does not exist at /var/www/html/magento23/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:29)"} []

**Is this module not compatible with Magento version 2.3.0** or what can be issues behind this error?

Thanks!

Comment: we can not support 3rd party modules

Comment: have you to run the `setup:di:compile` command after you successfully installed the external or 3rd party module.

Comment: My application is already in development mode so its not necessary to run such command.